# mysqli->insert_id always returns 0 in PHP after move to new server

Tags: php, mysqli, insert, mariadb, auto-increment

I have a number of web-apps that depend on `mysqli->insert_id`, it always returns `0` after having moved to a new server.

I created an isolated test script to just connect to the database, insert a record and output the result of `mysqli->insert_id`.  It always returns `0`.

- I've set `MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL`
- There are no connection or query errors
- I've confirmed that it is, in fact, inserting the record into the database.

If I run the exact same `insert` query in the mysql shell on the same server, I can query `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` and it gives me the last inserted ID as expected.

Is there a PHP or MySQL configuration I'm missing?

**EDIT**: I know they're supposed to be code-compatible, but the server is actually running MariaDB if that makes any difference.

Comment: Can you show us that isolated test script?

Comment: Please update your question with the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` Replace `tablename` with the affected table from your INSERT query.

Comment: Does `$mysqli->query("select last_insert_id()")->fetch_row()[0]` work on the new server?

Comment: I think I figured it out... for some reason, it only works on this new server if `insert_id` is called immediately following the most recent `INSERT` query.  If I execute any other query (including `SELECT`, `DELETE`, and `UPDATE`), it voids the value of `insert_id`.  Perhaps something changed in the implementation of this property between the PHP and/or MySQL versions on the old server vs. the new server?

Comment: @RecoveringNerdaholic that is the expected behavior according to the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php). `The value of the AUTO_INCREMENT field that was updated by the *previous query*. Returns zero if there was no previous query on the connection or if the query did not update an AUTO_INCREMENT value.` So if the previous query issued was not an INSERT that set a value in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, the result from `$mysqli->insert_id` is expected be 0

Comment: That's interesting -- and frustrating -- since **(a)** that was not the behavior on the previous host, despite running the identical PHP version and **(b)** it's inconsistent with MySQL's own behavior

Comment: @RecoveringNerdaholic - Sometimes "two wrongs make a right" -- You did not follow the documentation ("immediately"), and neither did it (by not returning 0).